# Which big number is bigger?

Tags: code-golf

**Input**

Integers a1, a2, a3, b1, b2, b3 each in the range 1 to 20.

**Output**

```
True if a1^(a2^a3) > b1^(b2^b3) and False otherwise.
```

^ is exponentiation in this question.

**Rules**

This is code-golf. Your code must terminate correctly within 10 seconds for any valid input on a standard desktop PC.

You can output anything Truthy for True and anything Falsey for False.

You can assume any input order you like as long as its specified in the answer and always the same.

For this question your code should always be correct. That is it should not fail because of floating point inaccuracies.  Due to the limited range of the input this should not be too hard to achieve.

**Test cases**

```
3^(4^5) > 5^(4^3)
1^(2^3) < 3^(2^1)
3^(6^5) < 5^(20^3)
20^(20^20) > 20^(20^19)
20^(20^20) == 20^(20^20)
2^2^20 > 2^20^2
2^3^12 == 8^3^11
1^20^20 == 1^1^1
1^1^1 == 1^20^20
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93104/discussion-on-question-by-anush-which-big-number-is-bigger).

Answer (score 16):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>31</s> 29 bytes

*-2 bytes thanks to Grimy*

```perl6
*.log10* * ***>*.log10* * ***
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYvRCsIwDEXf@xV5EGkr2KZ1Q53bl0hBcB2Dzsn2NNRvrwkIMgLJuZeTZzulMg8LbGOd9T6NHVoNNFo365grEccJZOof7azgJQCGc2eu952piOfbAhHeGyM@2Qd5CIWCBgomrwQG6ejCpQbPiErQLVmiiixnWaPN5Cz//gKeVj3p/yRcoLEsB24o@4COpSMTfgE)

Believe it or not, this is *not* an esolang, even if it is composed of mostly asterisks. This uses [Arnauld's formula](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/184737/76162), with log10 instead of ln.

Comment: I believe this fails for `2^3^12 == 8^3^11`.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen This should be fixed now. let me know if it fails for anything else

Comment: [-2 by removing the unneeded spaces](https://tio.run/##VYvRCsIwDEXf@xV5EGkr2KZ1Q53bl0hBcB2Dzsn2NNRvrwkIMgLJuZeTZzulMg8LbGOd9T6NHVoNNFo365grEccJZOof7azgJQCGc2eu952piOfbAhHeGyM@2Qd5CIWCBgomrwQG6ejCpQbPiErQLVmiiixnWaPN5Cz//gKeVj3p/yRcoLEsB24o@4COpSMTfgE)

Comment: @Grimy Thanks! I could have sworn I tried that...

Answer (score 8):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 39 bytes

```r
function(x,y,z)rank(log2(x)*(y^z))[1]<2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY7LTsMwEEX3@YqRurHRVOrYBYHUVGIBK1Y8VggkJ3Ueakgq44q0iG8PtqFpG6jHsq25Z66v6UZQ6GqlDWTrOrVlU4NtIFVVBbbQ@@ZHaQtQJl@/6dq@Q1kHWbcrnVq9gMYstIkyiPsJpgiVQCUxIUwEJpJ/5iz17YQ4uofrifCQXuRfUQ5x14@3uMEtN6pesqrJBWv5Gdu8bjl/ppeZ6DImcYrnrqYoOfyuEcxhPJ7D7fXdw02UMUKB0pVAOmBmgXm8f/KIxItgIyZ7nwHipMNNV/zvTwNGTAITH9m4GF4KB/8/sI9LAi/9RT1zZEO7GL5OIT@1CzJEum8)

Returns FALSE when `a > b` and TRUE if `b < a`

Comment: This is wrong for `f(2,2,20,2,20,2)`

Comment: Fixed, using your suggestion to @Arnauld answer ;)

Comment: I believe this fails for `2^3^12 == 8^3^11`.

Comment: Fails for both `1^20^20 == 1^1^1` and `1^1^1 == 1^20^20`.

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>11</s> <s>9</s> <s>11</s> 7 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
.²Šm*`›
```

Port of [*@Arnauld*'s JavaScript](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/184737/52210) and [*@digEmAll*'s R](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/184738/52210) approaches (I saw them post around the same time)
-2 bytes thanks to *@Emigna*
+2 bytes as bug-fix after *@Arnauld*'s and *@digEmAll*'s answers contained an error
-4 bytes now that a different input order is allowed after *@LuisMendo*'s comments

Input as `[a1,b1]`, `[a3,b3]`, `[a2,b2]` as three separated inputs.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9f79CmowtytRIeNez6/z/aSMcolivayABC6RgZxAIA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W/hphSdaKiTZBhrq2Tv6RJqr6SjEJ1orJNkDBEIgwgY6SQZQQTsIyOUFB61TVJQsv@vd2jT0QW5WgmPGnb91/kfbaxjGssVbapjDCRNdEyApCGYbaxjCCSNdIzAbIQaMx0jA5CEAZw2tMTPx0@DLQDxIByImAXIGUY6hoZgy41jAQ).

**Explanation:**

```python
.²       # Take the logarithm with base 2 of the implicit [a1,b1]-input
  Š      # Triple-swap a,b,c to c,a,b with the implicit inputs
         #  The stack order is now: [log2(a1),log2(b1)], [a2,b2], [a3,b3]
   m     # Take the power, resulting in [a2**a3,b2**b3]
    *    # Multiply it with the log2-list, resulting in [log2(a1)*a2**a3,log2(b1)*b2**b3]
     `   # Push both values separated to the stack
      ›  # And check if log2(a1)*a2**a3 is larger than log2(b1)*b2**b3
         # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Comment: You second version can be **εć.²š]P`›**

Comment: @Emigna Ah nice, I was looking at an approach with `ć`, but completely forgot about using `š` (not sure why now that I see it, haha). Thanks!

Comment: This seems to be incorrect (because Arnauld's answer was incorrect until the recent fix).

Comment: @Anush Fixed and 4 bytes saved by taking the inputs in a different order now. :)

Answer (score 5):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 56 bytes

```java
(a,b,c,d,e,f)->a>Math.pow(d,Math.pow(e,f)/Math.pow(b,c))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVJdaoNAEH7vKQZBcGFjoyalSWj60OdAIY@Swqprahp/0E1CCR6g9@jJehE77rq2sYXALvPtzDfzjePs2JGNdtFbE@5ZVcGKJRmcbwCKMjkywSHJBC9jFnJ4zk94nvK0YCWXHIAgz/ecZRAqr4VsYLRNgkCZUJlIGa5MTBaYXrcyh2CfhFAJJtAc8ySCFFuw1qJMsq2/AVZuK9KpXXYQpgU8QGMxGtCQRpTTmIyWbLli4tUu8pMV0R62sdv@hXxCmoWsie34G9QRvBIV1lNKAGfwKEwoTOVB4EFN@5hDwaUtw5PA@R1D153Oc8eDxNYxvM7sGsMdXzCkpvR3ZhDFDhw09x0aNq5l1RlE@/NXdyZLOuqrJ8Oo9tGep6O1mnScl5actpz1XE2c9AMfrBL@CvzBtl6sluyPN1Rm@Y4GrgaeBhMNphuy6Eqv3yvBUzs/CBvXOhOxZZjRi4XXjAiYFfy8zMzo8v8X0909grE0YA7G18encb2HWq573XwD)

### Credits

- [@Ørjan Johansen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/66041/%c3%98rjan-johansen) for finding a bug in my solution.
- Saved 10 bytes by reusing [@tsh's advantageous operands agencing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/184819/16236).

Comment: I believe this fails for `2^3^12 == 8^3^11`.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen Fixed

Answer (score 4):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 23 bytes

```
#2^#3Log@#>#5^#6Log@#4&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n277X9koTtnYJz/dQdlO2TRO2QzMNFH7H1CUmVei4JAebaxjomMKhCY6xrFccFFDHSMdYyA00jFEEjXWMQOrNTJAUQzkIiNDS9xyRgax//8DAA)

Comment: This doesn't terminate for a1=20, a2=20, a3=20.

Comment: @Anush fixed...

Comment: Too bad about overflow, otherwise `##>0&@@(##^1&@@@#)&` is only 19 bytes and even more mind-bogglingly un-Mathematica-like than the code above. (infput format `{{a,b,c},{d,e,f}}`)

Answer (score 3):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup><s>11</s></sup> 9 bytes

```
>&(^.@^/)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/7dQ04vQc4vQ1/2typSZn5CsYKtgqGCuYKJgqpAGxiYIxRNgAKGyoYASUSgNiIwVDhLCxghlUtZEBTDnIFCAPjCqAchC2oWUFQhumNJCNpBsEIZJguYr/AA)

Arguments given as lists.

- `>` is the left one bigger?
- `&(...)` but first, transform each argument thusly:
- `^.@^/` reduce it from the right to the left with exponention.  But because ordinary exponentiation will limit error even for extended numbers, we take the logs of both sides

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 68 bytes

```python
lambda a,b,c,d,e,f:log(a,2)*(b**c)>log(d,2)*(e**f)
from math import*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY3NCsMgEITveQqPKnOImpa20D5JL@ZHE4hRxEuf3hqhkBzKLrvMN8Nu@KTZbypb8iTvvGrXj5po9BgwYoJ5rN5SDck47Tkf2GvXY9UT54Y1JnpHnE4zWVzwMfEc4rIlaqlCh0upDoqx5kcFJFQpCXGgCteale0pXOSxxf2/J9ujV87vrI4TVxASt32V9/kL)

Port of @Arnualds answer, but with the base for log changed.

Comment: `^` is called `**` in Python. And with that changed, you won't be able to run all the OP's test cases.

Comment: Should be all fixed now, 66 bytes though.

Comment: I believe this fails for `2^3^12 == 8^3^11`.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen should be fixed

Comment: Seems like it. Apart from the logarithmic base change for the fix, this looks like Arnauld's method.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen I thought that too but then the ordene confused me. I see it know.

Comment: you don't need the extra sets of brackets around the exponents

Answer (score 3):

## [Clean](https://github.com/Ourous/curated-clean-linux), 44 bytes

```
import StdEnv
$a b c d e f=b^c/e^f>ln d/ln a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY1BS8NAEIXPza94hx4UJrRJtCi0nvQgeLLHNIXJ7mwb2GxKsyr@eddNCLYHYXi8@fbNW2WFXWg7/WEFLTcuNO2pO3tsvX5xn8mcUUNBQ2A29V4tZG@erINeROGw9RyzG5RzXAWx26FkQk1QBE0QgqmwTuMPJ9wM4rt3YXsLL71X3EtfJV9HOcsFDK3JbFaiINwR7seJpqhoxBkhp@GxGE024bitpnS@/EtHez3Z4784X04l@VA5nE96wQVlUR9Gk1VV@FHG8qEP6etbeP523DYqLjakxnDv05b98Rc)

Uses an adaptation of Arnauld's formula.

Comment: I believe this fails for `2^3^12 == 8^3^11`.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen Fixed.

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 11 bytes

```
2(?9•??e*)>
```

I'm beginning to understand Vyxal.

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=2%28%3F9%E2%80%A2%3F%3Fe*%29%3E&inputs=3%0A2%0A1%0A1%0A2%0A3&header=&footer=)

Comment: [11 bytes](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=2%28%3F9%E2%80%A2%3F%3Fe*%29%3E&inputs=3%0A2%0A1%0A1%0A2%0A3&header=&footer=)

Comment: @lyxal Why did I not think of that.

Comment: [9 bytes](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=2%28%3F%3F%3Fee%29%3E&inputs=3%0A2%0A1%0A1%0A2%0A3&header=&footer=)

Comment: @AaronMiller That doesn't work because time complexity.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 13 bytes

Uses the method from [Arnauld's JS answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/184737/47066)

```
2F.²IIm*ˆ}¯`›
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fyE3v0CZPz1yt0221h9YnPGrYBRTjAkIDKAEA)

Comment: This doesn't terminate for a1=20, a2=20, a3=20.

Comment: @Anush: Seems to [terminate](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9f79Du3GK9Q6tzHzXs@v8/2shAB4xiuaKNdIx1TGIB) in less than a second to me.

Comment: you have to set all the variables to 20. See https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9f79Du3GK9Q6tzHzXs@v8/2shAB4xiuRBMAA

Comment: @Anush: Ah, you meant `b1=b2=b3=20` ,yeah that doesn't terminate.

Comment: Yes, sorry. That is what I meant.

Comment: Ah, you edited and undeleted a few seconds before I finished my answer.. Your alternative is the same as I had. :D

Comment: @Anush: It is fixed now. Thanks for pointing out my mistake :)

Comment: This seems to be incorrect (because Arnauld's answer was incorrect until the recent fix).

Comment: @Anush: Yes, this had the same issue, which should now be fixed.

Comment: I'm a bit confused that you had to fix it, because when I tried to check my test case on all the answers with TIOs, the 05AB1E ones looked like they worked. Hm, trying the old TIO again it may be that your arguments are in the opposite order of what I thought.

Answer (score 2):

### Excel, 28 bytes

```
=B1^C1*LOG(A1)>E1^F1*LOG(D1)
```

Excel implementation of the same formula already used.

Comment: My understanding is that Excel has 15 digits of precision, so there may be cases where rounding result in this returning the wrong answer.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript, 51 bytes

```
f=(a,b,c,h,i,j)=>(l=Math.log)(a)*b**c-l(h)*i**j>1e-8
```

<s>Surprisingly, the test cases doesn't show any floating-point error. I don't know if it ever does at this size.</s>

This just compares the logarithm of the numbers.

Equality tolerance is equal to `1e-8`.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Alas this does fail with my `2^3^12 == 8^3^11` test case. In fact your answer is very similar to the original answer by Arnauld (sadly deleted rather than fixed) that inspired most of those which failed it.

Comment: @Ørjan Johansen Moved `l(h)` to the right, and maybe it works now?

Edit: Wait, it doesn't.

Comment: Added equality tolerance `0.01`.

Comment: I did a quick search and a tolerance should work, but this is a bit too high. The highest you need to exclude is `(5.820766091346741e-11,(8.0,3.0,11,2.0,3.0,12))` (my test case), and the lowest you need to include is `(9.486076692724055e-4,(17.0,19.0,1,3.0,7.0,2))` (`3^7^2 > 17^19^1`.) So something like `1e-8` should be safely in the middle and the same byte length.

Comment: @Ørjan Johansen Ok, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## TI-BASIC, <s>27</s> 31 bytes

```
ln(Ans(1))Ans(2)^Ans(3)>Ans(5)^Ans(6)(ln(Ans(4
```

Input is a list of length \$6\$ in `Ans`.
Outputs true if the first big number is greater than the second big number.  Outputs false otherwise.

**Examples:**

```
{3,4,5,5,4,3
   {3 4 5 5 4 3}
prgmCDGF16
               1
{20,20,20,20,20,19       ;these two lines go off-screen
{20 20 20 20 20 19}
prgmCDGF16
               1
{3,6,5,5,20,3
  {3 6 5 5 20 3}
prgmCDGF16
               0
```

**Explanation:**

```
ln(Ans(1))Ans(2)^Ans(3)>Ans(5)^Ans(6)(ln(Ans(4   ;full program
                                                 ;elements of input denoted as:
                                                 ; {#1 #2 #3 #4 #5 #6}

ln(Ans(1))Ans(2)^Ans(3)                          ;calculate ln(#1)*(#2^#3)
                        Ans(5)^Ans(6)(ln(Ans(4   ;calculate (#5^#6)*ln(#4)
                       >                         ;is the first result greater than the
                                                 ; second result?
                                                 ; leave answer in "Ans"
                                                 ;implicit print of "Ans"
```

---

**Note:**  TI-BASIC is a tokenized language.  Character count does ***not*** equal byte count.

Comment: I’m not that familiar with TI-BASIC, but this seems to be `log(x) × y × z` rather than `log(x) × y ^ z`. This won’t necessarily lead to the same ordering as the original inequality.

Comment: @NickKennedy Yes, you are correct about that!  I'll update the post to account for this.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 bytes

```
l⁵×*/}>/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/nUePWw9O19Gvt9P@HWx9aqv@oYa6GtUq4yqOmNUBkdGiZNVBEEy5gfGhZ1LGuLBCnYY6ClpYCUDbrUeM@HYVjXTogIV07kJDO4eX6XIfbgcoi//@P5oqONtZRMI3VUYiONtFRMAExTHUUjGNjY3WAcoYgJkjOSEfBCMQAKjaEysH1mQHlDNA0GhnABJGYIJahJSEVQBZUBdROMAMhDZWFuRbkDrAyIyTbdRQsYHLGUGcb4ZIzBIoYgjzFFQsA)

Based on [Arnauld’s JS answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/184737/42248). Expects as input `[a1, b1]` as left argument and `[[a2, b2], [a3, b3]]` as right argument.

Now changed to use log to the base 10 which as far as correctly handles all the possible inputs in the range specified. Thanks to Ørjan Johansen for finding the original problem!

Comment: I believe this fails for `2^3^12 == 8^3^11`.

Comment: Your Python TIO is incorrect.. You have `8*` instead of `8**`. @ØrjanJohansen is indeed correct that [`2**(3**12) > 8**(3**11)`](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EQ8NIQUtLQcNYS8vQSFNTwU5BwwIuYKipqfn/PwA) is falsey, since they are equal.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen oops. Yes they are indeed equal. The reason the original two are marked as different relates to floating point error.

Answer (score 1):

## bc -l, 47 bytes

```
l(read())*read()^read()>l(read())*read()^read()
```

with the input read from `STDIN`, one integer per line.

`bc` is pretty fast; it handles a=b=c=d=e=f=1,000,000 in a little over a second on my laptop.

Comment: I love a bc answer! Just need one in bash now :)

Answer (score 1):

## [C++ (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 86 bytes

Thanks to @ØrjanJohansen for pointing out a flaw in this and @Ourous for giving a fix.

```cpp
#import<cmath>
int a(int i[]){return pow(i[1],i[2])/pow(i[4],i[5])>log(i[3])/log(*i);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVPNboMwDD7DU3jdBVaqkv5pA1Zphx32DCgHlEKXigKCoE6rePV1doC1VKsKcuIv9ue/KKIoJlshTqdHuS/yUgViH6nPtSkzBZFFqwy5fSxjVZcZFPnBkiHjjgxn3J62cEFwye11mm8RztFA2pO0/QbDZiKtNzEEMq9UGUf7tamD7yOZWTYcTUMnyYpahRxe4Th3Fs4S/4Uzb/wLaxXycKU9AEwAMAx0BVigLDshfd44JpoYqjOCnZDOWhPB1QVr5jo9i9RrYS@3bTO3s3UZ9Fm/n02UkaHyjDsBxhrT6JvLa9V2R60hgxHN/VvYldYSk7yE9naQ5fq4BVDJ7zhPrHZY9nQAQ5fbPozHUk/cqNTG8wRmhiCA0Qe5eFgajDD0OfbO6ycvecsbEnea7bSsZhD23odE7Rxnm5Ti6pPR@1cRCxVvPBgR7icj@U3Gm1B1lFLtmhFZFwVfMqhCmWBb8PB6d1AwAfZfv4NodIOm0b0L1zeb049I0mhbnSaHXw)

Takes input as a 6-integer array. Returns 1 if \$a^{b^c} > d^{e^f}\$, 0 otherwise.

Comment: The formula after taking `log` twice should be `i[2]*log(i[1])+log(log(*i))`. E.g. the current one will fail for `2^2^20 > 4^2^18`.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen: good catch! I guess I have to use the `pow` method then.

Comment: The alternate one has the `2^3^12 == 8^3^11` problem I've pointed out for others.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen: well, I guess I'm using your fixed formula then.

Comment: Oh, I'm afraid that formula is only mathematically correct. It still has a floating point error problem, just with a different case, `2^3^20 == 8^3^19`. In fact on average the power method fails for fewer, probably because it tends to multiply by powers of two exactly. Others have managed to make it work by just tweaking it slightly.

Comment: You can use this for [86 bytes](https://tio.run/##hVPNboMwDD7DU3jdBVaqkv5pA1Zphx32DCgHlEKXigKCoE6rePV1doC1VKsKcuIv9ue/KKIoJlshTqdHuS/yUgViH6nPtSkzBZFFqwy5fSxjVZcZFPnBkiHjjgxn3J62cEFwye11mm8RztFA2pO0/QbDZiKtNzEEMq9UGUf7tamD7yOZWTYcTUMnyYpahRxe4Th3Fs4S/4Uzb/wLaxXycKU9AEwAMAx0BVigLDshfd44JpoYqjOCnZDOWhPB1QVr5jo9i9RrYS@3bTO3s3UZ9Fm/n02UkaHyjDsBxhrT6JvLa9V2R60hgxHN/VvYldYSk7yE9naQ5fq4BVDJ7zhPrHZY9nQAQ5fbPozHUk/cqNTG8wRmhiCA0Qe5eFgajDD0OfbO6ycvecsbEnea7bSsZhD23odE7Rxnm5Ti6pPR@1cRCxVvPBgR7icj@U3Gm1B1lFLtmhFZFwVfMqhCmWBb8PB6d1AwAfZfv4NodIOm0b0L1zeb049I0mhbnSaHXw "C++ (gcc) – Try It Online")

Comment: @Οurous: thanks for the fix! updated.

Comment: Suggest `int*i` instead of `int i[]`

Answer (score 1):

## APL(NARS), chars 36, bytes 72

```
{>/{(a b c)←⍵⋄a=1:¯1⋄(⍟⍟a)+c×⍟b}¨⍺⍵}
```

Here below the function z in (a b c )z(x y t) would  return 1 if a^(b^c)>x^(y^t) else would return 0;
test

```
  z←{>/{(a b c)←⍵⋄a=1:¯1⋄(⍟⍟a)+c×⍟b}¨⍺⍵}
  3 4 5 z 5 4 3
1
  1 2 3 z 3 2 1
0
  3 6 5 z 5 20 3
0
  20 20 20 z 20 20 19
1
  20 20 20 z 20 20 20
0
  2 2 20 z 2 20 2
1
  2 3 12 z 8 3 11
0
  1 20 20 z 1 1 1
0
  1 1 1 z 1 20 20
0
  1 4 5 z 2 1 1
0
```

{(a b c)←⍵⋄a=1:¯1⋄(⍟⍟a)+c×⍟b} is the function p(a,b,c)=log(log(a))+c*log(b)=log(log(a^b^c))
and if aa=a^(b^c) with a,b,c >0 and a>1 bb=x^(y^t) with x,y,t >0 and x>1  than

```
aa>bb <=> log(log(a^b^c))>log(log(x^y^t))  <=>  p(a,b,c)>p(x,y,t)
```

There is a problem with the function p: When a is 1, log log 1 not exist so I choose to represent that with the number -1; when a=2 so log log a is a negative number but > -1 .

PS. Seen the function in its bigger set in which is defined

```
p(a,b,c)=log(log(a))+c*log(b)
```

appear range for a,b,c in 1..20 is too few... If one see when it overflow with log base 10, the range for a,b,c could be 1..10000000 or bigger for a 64 bit float type.