# Which really big number is bigger?

Tags: code-golf, math, restricted-time

This question is tricky (and in particular harder than [Which big number is bigger?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/184734/which-big-number-is-bigger)), for those who like more challenging puzzles.

**Input**

Integers a1, a2, a3, a4, a5,  b1, b2, b3, b4, b5 each in the range 1 to 10.

**Output**

```
True if a1^(a2^(a3^(a4^a5))) > b1^(b2^(b3^(b4^b5))) and False otherwise.
```

^ is exponentiation in this question.

**Rules**

This is code-golf. Your code must terminate correctly within 10 seconds for any valid input on [TIO](https://tio.run/#).  If your language is not on TIO, the code should finish under 10 seconds on your machine.

You can output anything Truthy for True and anything Falsey for False.

**Test cases**

Recall that by the rules of exponentiaon,  a1^(a2^(a3^(a4^a5))) == a1^a2^a3^a4^a5.

```
10^10^10^10^10 > 10^10^10^10^9
1^2^3^4^5 < 5^4^3^2^1
2^2^2^2^3 > 10^4^3^2^2
6^7^8^9^10 is not bigger than 6^7^8^9^10
10^6^4^2^2 < 10^6^2^4^2
2^2^2^2^10 > 2^2^2^10^2
10^9^8^7^6 < 6^7^8^9^10 
3^1^10^10^10 > 2^1^10^10^10 
9^10^10^10^10 < 10^9^10^10^10
```

**New test cases from Kevin Cruijssen**

```
[10,10,10,10,10, 10,10,10,10,9] #true
[2,2,2,2,3,      10,4,3,2,2]    #true
[2,2,2,2,10,     2,2,2,10,2]    #true
[10,10,10,10,10, 9,10,10,10,10] #true
[3,2,2,1,1,      2,5,1,1,1]     #true
[2,2,3,10,1,     2,7,3,9,1]     #true
[7,9,10,10,10,   6,9,10,10,10]  #true
[3,2,2,2,2,      2,2,2,2,2]     #true
[8,3,1,2,1,      2,2,3,1,1]     #true
[2,4,2,1,1,      3,3,2,1,1]     #true
[5,4,3,2,1,      1,2,3,4,5]     #true

[1,2,3,4,5,      5,4,3,2,1]     #false
[6,7,8,9,10,     6,7,8,9,10]    #false
[10,6,4,2,2,     10,6,2,4,2]    #false
[10,9,8,7,6,     6,7,8,9,10]    #false
[1,10,10,10,10,  1,10,10,10,9]  #false
[2,4,1,1,1,      2,2,2,1,1]     #false
[2,2,2,1,1,      2,4,1,1,1]     #false
[2,5,1,1,1,      3,2,2,1,1]     #false
[4,2,1,1,1,      2,4,1,1,1]     #false
[2,4,1,1,1,      4,2,1,1,1]     #false
[2,3,10,1,1,     8,3,9,1,1]     #false
[8,3,9,1,1,      2,3,10,1,1]    #false
[2,4,1,1,1,      3,3,1,1,1]     #false
[2,2,1,9,9,      2,2,1,10,10]   #false
[2,2,1,10,10,    2,2,1,9,9]     #false
[1,1,1,1,1,      1,2,1,1,1]     #false
```

Comment: I'm VTC'ing this, even though it isn't a dupe; it's just too close to a challenge you posted 4 hours prior and shows a lack of effort to think up unique challenges.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn Can I politely but firmly disagree? a) this question now has this at the top "question may already have an answer here:" which is just completely wrong.  Solutions to the linked question are completely incorrect for this problem. Solutions to this question will be in no way competitive for the linked question.  b) Second, it's not a lack of effort!  There are two completely different questions you can ask on the same topic and I thought that was really interesting. You may not find it interesting but that's a different issue.

Comment: I feel like 9 people agreed on my point with their votes; but, as you say, it's your choice to keep it even though it has 9 downvotes. Was just shedding some light on why there may be downvotes.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn I couldn't delete it even if I wanted to could I?  The question received a number of downvotes before I improved it. For example, I didn't realise there was a restricted-time tag for example which looks perfect for this question.  But however you slice it, "This question may already have an answer here:" is simply factually incorrect.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn How is it incorrectly used?  I simply copied the model from https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/182202/next-number-with-k-fives .

Comment: Was just my two cents man, honestly; we don't need to go into detail here. Regret I even said anything; the last thing I wanted was an argumentative response. I was just stating why I gave a -1.

Comment: I'm voting to reopen this post because it has different difficulty parameter and the required approach to solve it is very different. [Meta post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14819/can-i-repost-a-challenge-with-different-difficulty-parameters).

Comment: [Suggested test cases](https://pastebin.com/xnwwALTA) (for the edge cases encountered by the Python, Ruby, Java, and 05AB1E answers)

Answer (score 8):

## Ruby, 150 bytes

See [revisions](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/185623/revisions) for previous byte counts.

```
->a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j{l=->s,t=c{Math.log(s,t)};y,z=l[l[g,b]]-d**e+l[h]*i**=j,l[l[a,f]*b**c,g];a>1?f<2?1:b<2||g<2?z>h:c<2||d<2?l[z,h]>i:y==0?a>f:y<0:p}
```

-10 bytes thanks to *@ValueInk*

+16 bytes thanks to *@RosLuP* for bugs.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##dVLbcoIwEH3vV3T6pOnaGogoaPAL@gVMHgC5qJmpo/iAl2@nCwkQ1E4YkpOzOZs92eM5Kqs9ryZ@CBHEsIEEUsgghy3srpJP/BMUPL7@hEX@JX@zEcLxfVnChctABhlEQkw2hCSfMsgF2RLCd1AzIaSCRITEkIll6NN1urLW1ItW1u2W4fLi515cgw0CGVwgF/7WKzmfrkM/9crV1Dvcq8O5OI0@iuM5@abex/itwTi97wM6hf8@VzQRFqhh13sMJwRDBvf7hXgl65pIRdjqBA4LZs1Me9UmV83Mcem2zNzUcQxgKg6GIha1XpNMa7eCM12PuoWNaGZeX5fUAvzZbSY6IB4uosvpNXRG7XrzGGkoT8nDW3SxYCi8yMieMra57D6oLlq/YFccdAUrwkF/F8rHftkpOhisLXBwYsbbuhg7x92nU8MeetFLTFdotc6YraQINuwG7QXYwxOsM@vpRJuDGd43hG4rqszpmQ72rUdF9Qc).

[Compare different base powers-towers (of 'height' five)?](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3227712)

#### Ungolfed code:

```
-> a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j {
    l =-> s, t = c {Math.log(s, t)}
    i **= j
    y = l[l[g, b]] - d ** e + l[h] * i
    z = l[l[a, f] * b ** c, g]
    if a == 1
        return p
    elsif f == 1
        return 1
    elsif b == 1 || g == 1
        return z > h
    elsif d == 1 || c == 1
        return l[z, h] > i
    elsif y == 0
        return a > f
    else
        return y < 0
    end
}
```

#### Code breakdown:

```
l =-> s, t = c {Math.log(s, t)}
```

This is the base `t` logarithm, which will be used to reduce the size of the numbers we are comparing. It defaults to base `c` when only one argument is given.

```
i **= j
y = l[l[g, b]] - d ** e + l[h] * i
z = l[l[a, f] * b ** c, g]
```

This updates `i = i ** j` since `i` never gets used on it's own, and `y` is the result of logging `b^c^d^e == g^h^i(^j)` twice and moving everything to one side. We then let `z = l[a, f] * b ** c` as the log base `g` of the log base `f` of `a ** b ** c`.

```
if a == 1
    return p
elsif f == 1
    return 1
```

`1^b^c^d^e = 1` is never greater than `f^g^h^i^j`, and likewise, `a^b^c^d^e` is always greater than `1^g^h^i^j = 1` if `a != 1`. Note that `return p` returns `nil`, which is falsey, and `return 1` returns `1`, which is truthy.

```
elsif b == 1
    return z > h
```

If `b == 1` or `g == 1`, then this reduces to comparing `a ** b ** c` to `f ** g ** h`, which is done with two logs to both sides.

```
elsif d == 1 || c == 1
    return l[z, h] > i
```

This compares `a ** b ** c` with `f ** g ** h ** i` by rearranging it as `log[log[b ** c * log[a, f], g], h]` compared to `i`. (Recall that `i **= j` in the beginning and `z = log[b ** c * log[a, f], g]`.)

```
elsif y == 0
    return a > f
else
    return y < 0
end
```

This compares the 4 highest powers after logging both sides twice. If they are equal, it compares the base.

Answer (score 5):

## Python 2, <s>671</s> <s>612</s> <s>495</s> <s>490</s> <s>611</s> 597 bytes

```python
lambda a,b:P(S(a,b))>P(S(b,a))if P(a)==P(b)else P(a)>P(b)
def S(a,b):
  if a and a[-1]==b[-1]:
    a.pop()
    b.pop()
    return S(a,b)
from math import*
L=log
E=exp
N=lambda m,n,x:N(m,n+1,L(x))if x>=1else N(m,n-1,E(x))if x<0else(m+n,x)
A=lambda a,n,x:(0,1)if a==1else(1,R(x,n)*L(a))if a<1else N(2,*C(L(L(a)),x,n-1))if n else(1,x*L(a))
def C(c,x,n):
 if c*n==0:return(0if c else n,x+c)
 z=R(x,n-1)
 if z<=L(abs(c)):return(0,E(z)+c)
 return N(1,*C(L(1-E(L(-c)-z)if c<0else 1+E(L(c)-z)),x,n-1))
def R(x,n):
 try:exec'x=E(x)'*n
 except:x=float('inf')
 return x
P=lambda b:b and N(0,*A(b[0],*P(b[1:])))or(0,1)
```

-59 bytes thanks to *@EmbodimentOfIgnorance*
-117 bytes thanks to *@Neil*
+121 bytes for about five bug-fixes, all found by *@ngn*

Takes the inputs as two lists. <s>NOTE: Also works with larger lists or those of unequal length.</s> EDIT: No longer true; it still works if `P(a)` and `P(b)` result in different tuples, but if they are the same this updated code above only works with lists with a fixed size of 5 now.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##lVRbb5swFH4ev8LaHmKnzuQLAYzqSlXVPVVVte0tiyIgZmNKICJkov3z3bGBlLapugmEL@f7znduye6@@VWV4jHXPx43yTZdJyihaXyHv2FYCbmwu5QmhBQ5usMJ0foOp8Rs9sYdL@zJW5scdYTYQwiQ4KVco2Qx40utU7vE3ofk867aYeJ9SIdNbZpDXfZUL6@rLdomzS9UbHdV3Uy9G72pfnrX2rQ771b38W1pSdv4FsN6xukNbl1s7YXmLipnmHF6PRjOmb3H2zOgEe9SH9O0bjCj3KIS3dExp19xS0syvcFd0sn54FfQ6RW@wc5AWyviACXqiW3HcdW4wpmF2HoAJJuWWrO4Sxcze@NICEI4y4iHHrRTBY8O/3CuwVW6xxkhRxZk9EAcui/bLWi6iPjsGr6zjMwebEBZlzHiZ/ba3R7jdcF1GUJoTX0fm9Zkk1bbck2mpYdMm5ldE7c631RJgydFmU@eNFvvbihgGqeuy7cQ2vQSpwu2pFMYhwWPl4SQqna1fbSCjdk32NBhQHZ1UTZo8tXsD5smntDc9Z9OfjTfDllmzNqs4dZo/WSYWLIL/o@pi/we44L@JjCXI3/X7c5kjeN2VuBdZs0h2cCNHVZ7cVXVNaAGjB3nZFDwoHirVZlszWqFtEYfV6ttUpSr1Uer4pL4Xh8MRWjBIbend0mfXagleRevnp2P@C8JdI4CngoqqU/nAJ3DKuHMX7sVtHtkF0GHE6/dBTSkEVWd9OjwWpfRANxYJ7Q7CHt8W9l5HLanpG09QC6kwXvSLyt6sqAD2gmCJ9XL87cqOTbSEe2Ufvc4bdHvT/jzj7A@79Od8XsTXciufe95s7BBFHCf0OW@m/YiS5qiKlFe1ehntclNvT@OPazDL8Kn7HMUSCW5jBTzOWc8IPTYqa43Y7Dy2ZzzgCkR@CwI5uTlrA3gEMBcyjCSAj6CCcFVSOjLqf4XinqTIYAhRRBIX8yVAk7ElE9ed/ff8EOLB7QENONqHkVSMjn3mYpUVx1/1On30eOGj9FRGEIQXAjJQxEo2bsW/@H6rUAioTgLhYoCBq/k5OVEjcE8DHgUCGh/FIk5CwPyfLCe0NwGQujor@a09Vm/Hv8C)

**Explanation:**

Golfed version of [this answer on math.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/398184/368863), so all credit goes to *@ThomasAhle*.

To quote his answer:

> The idea is to represent power towers as a single floating point
>   number with \$n\$ exponentiations: \$(x\mid n) := exp^n(x)\$. Normalizing
>   \$x\in[0,1)\$, this format allows easy comparison between numbers.
>
> What remains is a way to calculate \$a^{(x\mid n)}\$ for any real,
>   positive \$a\$. My Python code below is an attempt to do so, while being
>   as numerically stable as possibly, e.g. by using the log-sum trick. My
>   code runs in time proportional to the height of the tower (number of
>   `apow` calls) and the iterated-log of it's value (number of recursive
>   calls).
>
> I haven't been able to find two towers with values close enough to
>   case my method to fail. At least for integer exponents. With
>   fractional exponents it is possible to create very towers too close
>   for my representation to handle. E.g. \$2^{2^{2^{2^0}}}<2^{2^{2^{2^{(1/2)^{2^{2^{2^2}}}}}}}\$
>
> I would be interested in suggestions to other types of counter
>   examples, especially integer ones.
>
> It seems to me that for the problem to be in P, we need to
>   non-numerical methods. It doesn't seem unlikely at all, that certain
>   analytical cases are harder than P.
>
> **Examples:**
>
> ```python
> powtow([2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,4,2,2,2]) = (0.1184590219613409, 18)
> powtow([9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9]) = (0.10111176550354063, 18)
>
> powtow([2,2,5,2,7,4,9,3,7,6,9,9,9,9,3,2]) = (0.10111176550354042, 17)
> powtow([3,3,6,3,9,4,2,3,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3]) = (0.19648862015624008, 17)
> ```
>
> **Counter examples:**
>
> ```python
> powtow([2,2,2,2,2,2,2]) = (0.8639310719129168, 6)
> powtow([3,2,2,2,2,2,2]) = (0.8639310719129168, 6)
> ```

Regarding the counter examples, he mentions the following in the comment-section:

> I believe if we bound the exponents so \$1<a<100\$ (or maybe a much larger upper bound) we can use my method for comparing the height 3 or 4 head of the tower. It should be strong enough to tell us if they are equal or one is larger. Plan B is to choose the highest tower. Plan C is the interesting one: At this point the values of the rest of the tower only matter if the heads are equal, so we can walk down the towers in parallel, stopping as soon as we see a differing value.
>
> Hence the main thing to be proven is that once the head of a tower exceeds a certain point, and the rest of the exponents are bounded (and equally numerous), we can simply look at the top differing value. It's a bit counter intuitive, but it seems very likely from the simple inequalities you get.

Since plan A and B are irrelevant in this challenge, since the height is 5 for both power-towers we input, plan C it is. So I've changed `P(a)>P(b)` to `P(S(a,b))>P(S(b,a))if P(a)==P(b)else P(a)>P(b)` with the recursive function `S(a,b)`. If `P(a)` and `P(b)` result in the same tuple, the `P(S(a,b))>P(S(b,a))` will first remove trailing values which are equal at the same indices, before doing to same `P(A)>P(B)` check on these now shorter lists.

Comment: Thanks! In our case there aren't that many different possible inputs so maybe they can all be checked?

Comment: I also suck at golfing in python, but here is a [612 byter](https://tinyurl.com/y4sy47zj)

Comment: [559 bytes](https://tio.run/##bZLBjoMgEIbvPAW3DoqJ9Eik2U170qRp9tr0gBS3TRWNdRP05V2QutlN9kLkn5l/vhnsxuHWmu0817IprxJLWvITSLI7QUlQ1bcNbuRww/ema/shQoWo20@UC207dBSvIkMtP4KJGS3AEnKvsN0Jpuunxk5OGM1XOUu9Cq6AoMNaXvHwEUnnElUQSULQ2wFddYXfQdIlnXCEsbOQmWBtj40QKe/18NUbSCnz5lKEnsDoB1hqSFS4QZZItgZs0JzVg45iDwUsd@rSE@blYIkf8ZaOK8MelE9YCVT0p7lX8DKrw4yVN5nEAhAcXXzKhGtTPkG5MX6gc5hIyF9ZWJK7M1EkmTy2CtvCLPbyov5HyhypxwxDe8ihH7m2Wm2s8JvfRMaJ2irdDa/2uKpbOcDmbqrNLzOLTuujlLzE0lzdA5Tn9ELd73Bm/EJI2y/7nudv "Python 2 – Try It Online") based on @EmbodimentofIgnorance's code (also removed footer to fit link in comment box)

Comment: [495 bytes](https://tio.run/##bVHBauMwEL3rK4ZeIjkTsJxt2pqoUHpLoIS9ZoORHbk1xHJwvaDm57MjKUmbsNhYnpn35r0Z7b@Gj85mx1r9Oe50W241aCzzFdfiecVLweq@a6HVwwc07b7rh4Qt1a57Zwtl3J69qROpRYsuf@N0jiUuuROiqcE9K2l2nwZCYSJxcS7MU5/n7Zhogr2oi7Zvw1OUHqVVpHOJv7lDK5Il@QqV@blvhskrX/JQQOdFAsDCiegih21NDa@88hCRMyBIlVil0rw3w9/e8tRnAgnIwrgSDA4qqFLHgD/MFbUqP3klxIVFEx1EQMcMOZLRkZws6DupxOTgDVVxYpBjnw7Zi99gLk5I1ob@KzfOVCOn/LpGiWVgXGX2w0kV6l2nBz5qbD36FnZsdd5imZeg7Za8pJi88HKdbjCh21zLfCOE6Pqw4CO5KgqrW1MUoBTcFUWrG1sUd2QC9n1jB6j5WhL2@93gVeJpI66wmOEUf@E9we7pnFIsryEZxmcaO0VMdo2Z4QM@4lOU@xGIG18zonsyxiDz4f/VQqfz7y3Iz0ESDzi7kTv@Aw)

Comment: @EmbodimentofIgnorance Thanks! Completely forgot about `exec'...'*n`, and also forgot it's possible creating 'variables' for the `log`/`exp` like in C. :)

Comment: Fails for `[10,10,10,10,10]>[9,10,10,10,10]`

Comment: @EmbodimentofIgnorance Should be fixed now, thanks. I was afraid there might be some counter-examples where `P(a)==P(b)` even though the `a` and `b` are different and they shouldn't be equal. The linked answer also mentioned the counter-examples `[2,2,2,2,2,2,2]` and `[3,2,2,2,2,2,2]` which result in equal tuples. I've fixed this with plan C that he mentioned in the comment section, for which I added a quote and brief explanation at the bottom of my post.

Comment: You only use the function `R` once, so maybe you can just inline it?

Comment: https://tio.run/##PVFNj4IwEL33V4wnplgS6pE4JsZwI8bs1fVQsKwYKQTZpHLYv@62Rb304715b16n/WO8dGb1rOn7eVNteVagRJmpBZWgzPnYbK5QdwM04gqNganp0fG8qaFZ0PV0TOTJnQ@oONEBS65vdx2uG39j9dC10KrxAk3bd8MYs4Ju3Q/LSdue7enVshVG2GyPbl9KUaDlvoPdkAx@gUikyN/EOvU4tksn42xLn@TeBlMhfZWiWY5SfKEVhseFyxWY9dt3JeIdFhgIYX2TUGDgJbSzhp11DTusfAnPGLiSKjZEaTbo8XcwmHokiMBFWFacwUSWwTg8Mm11FU2U48Sj@C8xDLStdD9mE9W3To0YNaaOeHCd1uQalnesOP94Cy8NnjPicss5t0xytyYVTyYfu5rnAnLp4YB@XsUO7ymVWfha55KKeIvlMT2J2P3WUWYnznk3hAE@n/8

Comment: @EmbodimentofIgnorance There's still an outstanding call to `R` on line 5...

Comment: `exec'x=E(x)'*n` - this fails for n>1. missing `;` after `E(x)`?

Comment: fails for `[1,10,10,10,10],[1,10,10,10,9]`

Comment: @ngn Should be fixed now, as well as cases like `[2,2,1,9,9],[2,2,1,10,10]`. Can definitely be golfed again, though.. I'm pretty bad at Python golfing tbh.

Comment: `[1,1,1,1,1],[1,2,1,1,1]` raises an `IndexError`

Comment: `[2,4,1,1,1],[2,2,2,1,1]` - wrong result

Comment: @ngn dangit.. >.> Maybe I should have ported this to Java or 05AB1E, then I at least knew what I was doing and could easily fix these kind of issues.. I know what the issue is, will see if I can fix it. Once I've figured out how to properly split an integer-list in Python on a certain value (`1`) in this case..

Comment: you could use `a[:(a+[1]).index(1)]` to remove the first 1 and everything after it, but i'm not sure the rest of the algorithm is correct

Comment: @ngn I think the original algorithm (so `P(a)>P(b)`) is correct for lists of this size 5, except that I should remove equal pairs from the end of the inputs first. So `f([9,10,10,10,10],[10,10,10,10])` would becomes `f([9],[10])` and `f([2,4,1,1,1],[2,2,2,1,1])` would become `f([2,4],[2,2,2])`. Unless you find another counter-example. ;) PS: How to accomplish what I stated in this comment? I know how to remove all equal pairs with a `zip` and `zip*` back, but I only want to remove the trailing items which are equal.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen i don't think that works. consider `[2,4,2],[3,3,2]` - the first one is bigger (65536>19683), but if we remove the trailing 2s, it's the other way round (16<27)

Comment: @ngn Ah, crap, you're right.. Found a fix for that as well. Will update now, and hopefully you won't be able to find any more edge cases, haha. ;P (Read: thanks for finding all these edge cases.)

Comment: the follow output of your test program for above is it ok?
Result: False Succeeded: 
True  [2, 1, 1, 1, 1] [3, 1, 1, 1, 1]
Result: False  Succeeded: 
True  [10, 6, 4, 2, 2] [10, 6, 2, 4, 2]
etc

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>96</s> 104 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
3èI4èmU8.$`m©I7èI2è.n*I6èI1è.nI2è.n+Vнi0ë5èi1ë2ô1èßi¦2£`mIнI5è.n*I6è.nDI7èDi\1›·<žm*ë.n}®›ëXYQiнI5è›ëXY›
```

Port of [*@SimplyBeautifulArt*'s Ruby answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/185623/52210), so make sure to upvote him!

+8 bytes as work-around, because \$\log_1(x)\$ should result in `POSITIVE_INFINITY` for \$x\gt1\$ and `NEGATIVE_INFINITY` for \$x\lt1\$, but results in `0.0` for both cases instead in 05AB1E (i.e. test cases `[3,2,2,1,1,2,5,1,1,1]` (`POSITIVE_INFINITE` case) and `[2,4,1,1,1,3,3,1,1,1]` (`NEGATIVE_INFINITY` case).

Input as a list of ten integers: `[a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j]`.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f@PAKT5PDK3JDLfRUEnIPrfQ0BwoYHV6hl6flaQZkGoKYEAHtsAt7Mw0OrzY9vCLT8PBqo8NbgJKH52ceWmZ0aHFCrueFvZ6mcI16eS4go1wyYwwfNew6tN3m6L5crcOr9fJqD60DChxeHREZmAnRAeUCqf//o410THQMwdAYCMGsWAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##dVG9SsRAEH6V47A6l3D7kz8QrrkXsFCUGDiFK1LkLAQhxYGVtfgCFoJEAlaCIJxFFvt7hnuROLuzu9kEzAR25tuZb2b2u727vinW3X0ln9AW08nh8XkyXXRc1pWQdXmWBEersn2vYgCYrIPNrIrApcpF4Ph8vyvmsgllXVDZMPkJl/KlaN9Y@7oqq/2uCl1hsFkqqmVxRQ8P3@3Xye9POZNNsNm2HwDI5uLytMAKE8LRbeEjXZbROfnvT3OSMYLGFSDggMCDAewdwMcMfgTXHHPBGAn1SQ2Z5ldwDG6q4dgvj7zAEQ0M0ETR6AaG0tAL05Tr@RENzTY4DIco1Ly078m8QFdQB9g1qNvZPIKrnBOu7iw3cf0AjWDLBBfqXWSK9LAMr/TkiKeQFQM0zB8qNlZO4IhWIffWdmnhKWCWI9zLtc82zrW8wnsEpyAlCSqoYef3Eg85OMrkZqOQntoZzMN7EXE5uL4zNmJR5gk2llYMpbXcvM/Qk2s6r4wPy5hrz62X538).

**Explanation:**

```python
3èI4èm         # Calculate d**e
      U        # And pop and store it in variable `X`
8.$`m          # Calculate i**j
     ©         # Store it in variable `®` (without popping)
I7èI2è.n       # Calculate c_log(h)
 *             # Multiply it with i**j that was still on the stack: i**j * c_log(h)
I6èI1è.nI2è.n  # Calculate c_log(b_log(g))
 +             # And sum them together: i**j * c_log(h) + c_log(b_log(g))
  V            # Pop and store the result in variable `Y`

нi             # If `a` is 1:
 0             #  Push 0 (falsey)
ë5èi           # Else-if `f` is 1:
 1             #  Push 1 (truthy)
ë2ô1èßi        # Else-if the lowest value of [c,d] is 1:
 ¦2£`m         #  Calculate b**c
 IнI5è.n       #  Calculate f_log(a)
  *            #  Multiply them together: b**c * f_log(a)
   I6è.n       #  Calculate g_log(^): g_log(b**c * f_log(a))
 D             #  Duplicate it
  I7è          #  Push h
     Di        #  Duplicate it as well, and if h is exactly 1:
       \       #   Discard the duplicated h
       1›      #   Check if the calculated g_log(b**c * f_log(a)) is larger than 1
               #   (which results in 0 for falsey and 1 for truthy)
         ·<    #   Double it, and decrease it by 1 (it becomes -1 for falsey; 1 for truthy)
           žm* #   Multiply that by 9876543210 (to mimic POSITIVE/NEGATIVE INFINITY)
      ë        #  Else:
       .n      #   Calculate h_log(g_log(b**c * f_log(a))) instead
      }        #  After the if-else:
       ®›      #  Check whether the top of the stack is larger than variable `®`
ëXYQi          # Else-if variables `X` and `Y` are equal:
     нI5è›     #  Check whether `a` is larger than `f`
ë              # Else:
 XY›           #  Check whether `X` is larger than `Y`
               # (after which the top of the stack is output implicitly as result)
```

If anyone wants to try and golf it further, here is [a helper program](https://tio.run/##RY5NTsMwFITXySmeLJYWEuV3g1DZtVdASDwnL7VLIFHsInXHOdiCUA7Agk03zQV6Bi4Spk4KlkYafZp548qzcdL3aqpv6Un42ZOpgqUXLlfiiRuheuWt5OSl5oaDlGsKFQUr5ANnj@n00ANaxwKjRzW7Bq3S@ZAqnapcy7W6Oe3a2VnXJj@vb2BOL8Gujo8eRmB1BnCJ0KRrD3ChDeAF4Mk/3OeQSRJ4ht9toi1gz0ec5THzhVYy38d0EYMzBGg8Y@Lg9nOyff@bG8biCTv8Zlgp4rmP7nu3ofjmuu/vFCutDJRBOSRQAS0gCzloqe5/AQ) I've used to get the correct variables from the input-list.

Comment: Very impressed this has got under 100!  And thank you so much for adding the bounty.

Comment: @Anush I actually have the feeling 96 is pretty long, considering the non-golfing language Ruby got 151. ;p And np about the bounty. It's mainly for _@SimplyBeautifulArt_'s approach, but at the same time to give the challenge some attention. The reason it got downvoted is because you posted it a few hours after your earlier answer with 3 powers. I personally like this challenge, and was the first to upvote and answer it, but I can still kinda see the truth in the very first comment under the challenge post at the same time. Hopefully the bounty will make your challenge 0 or positive, though :)

Comment: I dream of a getting 0! :)

Comment: [2,1,1,1,1,3,1,1,1,1] result 1 instead has to result 0

Comment: @RosLuP Fixed, along with other INFINITY cases due to \$log_1(x)\$. Unfortunately the byte-count is now longer below 100.

Comment: it seems I remember that log has always base >1... How to define log_1 ? In code I use oo only for the case in which the 2 values are both infinite... So case when one value is infinite and other finite would be ok... The suspect the range of this exercise 1..10 is too few too...

Comment: @RosLuP Tbh I dunno, not that familiar with logarithms tbh.. In Java it uses `log_e(x)/log_e(1)` to accomplish `log_1(x)`; and in the Ruby it uses `Math.log(x,1)`. In my 05AB1E answer `.n` is a logarithm builtin accepting two numbers as argument (input and base) and also does `base_log(input)`. Maybe official logarithm always needs a base \$\gt1\$, but all three languages still accept it as valid input.

Answer (score 3):

### C, <s>168</s> 180 bytes

C port from Kevin Cruijssen's answer.

```c
#define l(a,b)log(a)/log(b)
z(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j){float t=pow(i,j),y=l(l(g,b),c)-pow(d,e)+l(h,c)*t,z=l(l(a,f)*pow(b,c),g);return~-a&&f<2|(b<2|g<2?z>h:c<2|d<2?l(z,h)>t:y?y<0:a>f);}
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##dVHbbsIwDH3nKxDTUMJcjbbcyvVtX7DHvYTSFqZQUAmagLFPX@fm1haYUjX2OfaxY4dOEoZ5/rSK4k0aNTlhsKR8lxBGX4trSRvnAoMQVhBBDAmsYQOf9BLzHRNNMdvvvkgBwGnGCScJ5kNInQLGDPrCyRr9joCz5BnEtFOQKEkhoZMsEscs/XFYux1PvW@yxF8y9Rbn@Xocor1Cm5MzrOlcjE@L07Q7ZvOYTq65eNzYPtukIiat59VH2oLH3WN6Y8s2KaGXxv4oDqT1nh2jFp00BHG78N8XyAAP1PELqIcXOjUC4dJ4pBlUPRngq3g8HvTl7VpJWacghmgGmhhWRQYVpyJXOxIfFWKykBa2ZXq6vC/fY/C@fp9qzEevr/XdsrpXcZBV83xj/GAGalLBykl8gA8aqc5L04xrIDvyFCnbM0yAkUMEb3Pqy7pfWk@N1aymMmDzvl5t8HoN4NfizZzu442@jdC4Xp8LI7U@TViv3PCtkq82VOnUxZTA9GO3XfHBRpmh2GO7uua/YcxZcsgdvv0D)

Comment: Hmmm... a port of a port *\*thonks\**

Comment: [Fails for `3,1,10,10,10,2,1,10,10,10`](https://tinyurl.com/y4ut5lfy) like my Java answer used to as well. And it's actually a port of @SimplyBeautifulArt's Ruby answer, since he's the one who came up with everything and fixed the bugs..

Answer (score 2):

## APL(NARS), chars 118, bytes 236

```
{p←{(a b c d)←⍵⋄a=1:¯1⋄b=1:⍟⍟a⋄(⍟⍟a)+(c*d)×⍟b}⋄(=/(a b)←{p 1↓⍵}¨⍺⍵)∧k←(∞ ∞)≡(m n)←{p(3↑⍵),*/3↓⍵}¨⍺⍵:(↑⍺)>↑⍵⋄k:a>b⋄m>n}
```

The function above call z, in "a z w" would return 1 if the number in a is greater than the number in w,
otherwise it would return 0.

If I have

```
f(a,b,c,d,e)=a^b^c^d^e
```

It will be f(aa)>f(bb) with both aa and bb array of 5 positive numbers if and only if
(if the a>1 of aa and bb) log(log(f(aa)))>log(log(f(bb))) one has to use the log() laws:

```
log(A*B)=log(A)+log(B)
log(A^B)=B*log(A)
```

for build v(aa)=log(log(aa))=v(a,b,c,d,e)=log(log(a))+log(b)*(c^(d^e))={p(3↑⍵),*/3↓⍵}
function and so the exercise is find when v(aa)>v(bb).

But there is a case where v(aa) and v(bb) are both infinite (APL has end the float space)
in that case i would use the unsecure function

```
s(a,b,c,d,e)=log(log(b))+log(c)*(d^e)={p 1↓⍵}
```

that i not fully understand if it is ok and it not take in count a parameter too...
test:

```
  z←{p←{(a b c d)←⍵⋄a=1:¯1⋄b=1:⍟⍟a⋄(⍟⍟a)+(c*d)×⍟b}⋄(=/(a b)←{p 1↓⍵}¨⍺⍵)∧k←(∞ ∞)≡(m n)←{p(3↑⍵),*/3↓⍵}¨⍺⍵:(↑⍺)>↑⍵⋄k:a>b⋄m>n}
  10 10 10 10 10 z 10 10 10 10 9
1
  1 2 3 4 5 z 5 4 3 2 1
0
  2 2 2 2 3 z 10 4 3 2 2
1
  10 6 4 2 2 z 10 6 2 4 2
0
  2 2 2 2 10 z 2 2 2 10 2
1
  10 9 8 7 6 z 6 7 8 9 10
0
  10 10 10 10 10 z 10 10 10 10 9
1      
  2 2 2 2 3   z    10 4 3 2 2
1
  2 2 2 2 10   z   2 2 2 10 2
1
  10 10 10 10 10 z 9 10 10 10 10
1
  3 2 2 1 1   z    2 5 1 1 1
1
  2 2 3 10 1  z    2 7 3 9 1
1
  7 9 10 10 10 z   6 9 10 10 10
1
  3 2 2 2 2    z   2 2 2 2 2
1
  3 10 10 10 10 z  2 10 10 10 10
1
  8 3 1 2 1    z   2 2 3 1 1
1
  2 4 2 1 1    z   3 3 2 1 1
1
  5 4 3 2 1    z   1 2 3 4 5
1
  1 2 3 4 5    z   5 4 3 2 1
0
  6 7 8 9 10    z  6 7 8 9 10
0
  10 6 4 2 2 z     10 6 2 4 2
0
  10 9 8 7 6  z   6 7 8 9 10
0
  1 10 10 10 10 z 1 10 10 10 9
0
  2 4 1 1 1 z     2 2 2 1 1
0
  2 2 2 1 1    z  2 4 1 1 1
0
  2 5 1 1 1   z   3 2 2 1 1
0
  4 2 1 1 1   z   2 4 1 1 1
0
  2 4 1 1 1   z   4 2 1 1 1
0
  2 3 10 1 1  z   8 3 9 1 1
0
  8 3 9 1 1   z   2 3 10 1 1
0
  2 4 1 1 1   z   3 3 1 1 1
0
  2 2 1 9 9   z   2 2 1 10 10
0
  2 2 1 10 10 z   2 2 1 9 9
0
  1 1 1 1 1   z   1 2 1 1 1
0
  1 1 1 1 2   z   1 1 1 1 1
0
  1 1 1 1 1   z   1 1 1 1 1
0
  9 10 10 10 10 z  10 9 10 10 10
1
  9 10 10 10 10 z  10 10 10 10 10
0
  10 10 10 10 10 z  10 10 10 10 10
0
  11 10 10 10 10 z  10 10 10 10 10
1
```

Comment: The tests in the challenge description are lacking some edge cases. Could you verify that it's also working for [all these test cases](https://pastebin.com/k0XtveTf)?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen the test 5 4 3 2 1 z 1 2 3 4 5 would result true n>1 your test would be wrong on that case

Comment: Ah oops, that one is indeed supposed to be true. Copy-paste error.. My bad. All the other test cases should be correct.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen      Here your test , if exclude the one above seems ok...

Comment: If all test cases are correct, then +1 from me. Looking forward seeing an explanation of your code. :)

Comment: Only logging twice leaves you vulnerable to fail test cases like `10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10`.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt 10 10 10 10 10 z 9 10 10 10 10 return 1 so the left > right... What does it mean"logging  twice"?

Comment: You said you calculated each by taking `log(log())`, but for that test case, the difference between `log(log(10^10^10^10^10))` and `log(log(9^10^10^10^10))` would require an absurd amount of accuracy to pick up on. You'd need to have a floating point with about `2e10` base 10 digits of accuracy. And this is ignoring the fact that both sides are approximately as large as `10^10^10`, which I find it hard to believe you were able to compute.

Comment: I'm not really sure how your code works, so I'm looking forward to that explanation. Perhaps it fails a test case like `10, 10, 2, 3, 10, 10, 10, 8, 3, 9`, which should return `0`.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt in that case Apl return infinity both side, and so code would use the s() function...

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt the test 10 10 2 3 10 z 10 10 8 3 9 return 0

Comment: Perhaps it fails `9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 9, 10, 10, 10`, which should return `1`, but `s(9,10,10,10,10) < s(10,9,10,10,10)`.

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, <s>299</s> <s>288</s> <s>286</s> <s>252</s> <s>210</s> <s>208</s> 224 bytes

```java
Math M;(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j)->{double t=M.pow(i,j),y=l(l(g,b),c)-M.pow(d,e)+l(h,c)*t,z=l(l(a,f)*M.pow(b,c),g);return a>1&&f<2|(b<2|g<2?z>h:c<2|d<2?l(z,h)>t:y==0?a>f:y<0);}double l(double...A){return M.log(A[0])/M.log(A[1]);}
```

Port of [*@SimplyBeautifulArt*'s Ruby answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/185623/52210), so make sure to upvote him!
-14 bytes thanks to *@SimplyBeautifulArt*.
+17 bytes for the same bug-fixes as the Ruby answer.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##pVVNb6MwEL33V1g5VHZxaICkaZImVS97S3el7q3qwYD5yFKIwGmVdvPbs8PwESDhtHL08HjGb8aPCd6IDzHcuH@OTiSyjKxFGH9fERLGSqaecCR5zk1Cftob6SjiUPAQwXO0ER1EF1Eieog@YoAYIm7YAqgOVwBroQKyXgDv7S3RpsTeK5kRlRAVSDSGTrKLFUQ@k5gsyZEKbnOHu1xyj/scaPmGDVffbrKzI0nUcq1vk0@ar/L9MqIR9bnNuMOGhQM2Mi2iAazcKP6FEYJ77KZwAzfjPlukUu3SmIiVcX3tPZh/qQ3gP5iPX6tg7sDchXlEv3jAVmq@Xy5Hj2LlzfcPI7Y4LMpiIlpMdF1/Yt8l5VqPEp8@vY7e2G01N95g1xEOuYXw0CGZEgoeH0noknd4EfRFpWHsv74RkfoZK14ECPY73algP0cTdFPUGPG@3wxFL@NMXgwr94zhAcYlP3hPk2ZAl7xpNeOsYjcMk0/waXTzYA25fwrTWds/bTLfNYzzHK3RdN/nGbCIMlu3hHFZoYU6dNyTUp7iCBZYk3Zu41Sg2TDaHEbtqeQwztUsda65Rtwqg172mZLverJT@hYaQUUxLT1VJ/wQUSZbnVBVy@sTNDPegdr3hZ6naaekO1TGLGJQpk7ADPZNwdfD0O7A3k4cF3pUjXbeIJX440v9U2rLrUu7qzfbu7vKPb70VurWNPh90Zptf714auIeeqtou/OjGUAwqyrvtk1jmdfBHYXrYfYlyEejAXubd9zTvFV@6xSKB29nahBZXSL80Dc/abjnf66P4gNYfBThsviV/yfgchDagA80G9FBdBGlNiAidslA89D2EQPEEHHT@z8r2YFhoKdyKwXINhmWq3okY18FlDEtlp94Z1Kmx7pz8ZYqxTgc/wE)

**Explanation:**

```java
Math M;                      // Math M=null on class-level to save bytes

(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j)->{     // Method with ten integer parameters and boolean return-type
  double t=M.pow(i,j),       //  Temp `t` = `i` to the power `j`
    y=l(l(g,b),c)            //  Temp `y` = `c`_log(`b`_log(`g`))
      -M.pow(d,e)            //  - `d` to the power `e`
      +l(h,c)*t,             //  + `c`_log(`h`) * `t`
    z=l(l(a,f)*M.pow(b,c),g);//  Temp `z` = `g`_log(`f`_log(`a`) * `b` to the power `c`)
  return a>1&&               //  If `a` is 1:
                             //   Return false
   f<2|(                     //  Else-if `f` is 1:
                             //   Return true
    b<2|g<2?                 //  Else-if either `b` or `g` is 1:
     z>h                     //   Return whether `z` is larger than `h`
    :c<2|d<2?                //  Else-if either `c` or `d` is 1:
     l(z,h)>t                //    Return whether `h`_log(`z`) is larger than `t`
    :y==0?                   //   Else-if `y` is 0:
      a>f                    //    Return whether `a` is larger than `f`
    :                        //   Else:
     y<0);}                  //    Return whether `y` is negative

// Separated method to calculate `B`_log(`A`) for inputs `A,B`
double l(double...A){return M.log(A[0])/M.log(A[1]);}
```

Comment: It seems to work fine if you use `x==y` instead of `M.abs(x-y)<1e-9`.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Wait, it does?.. Wtf. When I had my ungolfed version it didn't work for one test case. The string output was the same, but internally it ever so slightly differed.  The ungolfed version was your ungolfed version, before I changed it to the golfed ternary you have in your Ruby answer as well. Stupid floating point precision.. Will change it, since it works for the test cases in the current approach indeed. Thanks.

Comment: Lol, while you're at it you might want to look at my updates :^)

Comment: I can't help but wonder if you could avoid doing the `Math M` and go straight to defining a `p` for `M.pow`

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt In Java not unfortunately.. Have you seen my method `l`? ;p A method `p` would shortest be `double p(double...A){return Math.pow(A[0],A[1]);}`, so 3x `M.pow` is _definitely_ shorter. (And I also use the `Math M;` for the two `M.log`.)

Comment: `t` is can be removed to save one byte by putting it into `y` like I did. [TIO](https://tio.run/##NY1BDoIwEEWvwop0dKjAEmgJB2DHzrgolBaxEUNEQ9Cz1xJwM3mZvP9/L14i6OXNWiKwxgYltqhQY4dX7CHgixym2rRexUr6GN5k/eLMqoMhHTZwNMQQjTU4DjbDNUA6ts9pvHuCR76vsvhDGndkFuerv3luDVyLQAWoATvgVRIyNueCqyTkM6TfdB83ZANKaQHL3l1SM2hSnMMLnP4cXVzK2h8)

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Thanks. Will also update my 05AB1E answer with the same change. :)

Comment: Um... not sure about your math there on the byte count. It should be 209?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt 208 actually. The semi-colon between the lambda and loose method isn't counted towards the total byte-count. [This perhaps clarifies it a bit how it's usually counted.](https://tinyurl.com/y3mmjuct)

Comment: Hm okay, if you say so :-)

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Nvm about updating my 05AB1E answer with the same change. [The byte-count would remain 96.](https://tio.run/##dVHLSsQwFP2VYXClcZgkfa5m4zcIUoYZRRdZVBeCkMXAICK4E39AQZBKwZUrYTbND8w39EfqTW6SpoXpLe29J6cnJ6d395dX4qZ7kOoVazGdtM9vk@miy2ZH67L5lqmqJFPV7PZYJtBS3SJwIjkAkarK0/P9TsxVHatKUFUz9Qs09S6aL9Z8rku538nYS8DnqX6erUT7@LRpftrtn6ovVgJZOF23Lx/dBi7SFQWdk0N3viQFI1hcAxG8YAhgAPsG8LFCOMEyRy4UI7F5Uytm9DWcQpsbOA0/T4LBCw0K0EzLmA2spJWP7Kbc@Ec0tqdBMxymWPt3PfHrgCbgKkMDfYunTYw4wyWzE@I5sFKAhvxhwuOkI0zEJeqzcSajIDGbHuEB1x1zzHW6ft2gNnFKMkzcwL7vf8lQg2Os3hsFeu482J8TTMRz8Pi@nJPlPw)

Comment: @RosLuP Fixed by porting the Ruby fix.